# Java Interface Inner Class

Tags: java, interface, inner-classes

i'm still writing a Battleship game in java.
I'm having trouble to do it modular: I need to build the data classes (model) with an interface.
The idea i got is to build a class hierarchy like this:

BattleGrid => some methods, Grid => int rows, int cols, Cell[][] grid => char content

This means:
1. the public class is the BattleGrid class (which one that offers methods outside, like initGrid(), placeShip(), etc...);
2. then inside there is another class, the Grid, that contains the material grid and some info like grid rows and grid columns;
3. Inside every Cell, there is the content of that cell.
(obviously all with setters and/or getters)

The problems is: when i write this through a BattleGrid interface, inner classes are automatically declarated as public static.

Which is the proper way to do this kind of structure??

Comment: Not sure from where comes the irresistible urge to have inner classes. Anyway it would be clearer if you'd present a code sample demonstrating your problem.

Comment: Why you would like to have a BattleGrid interface and inside a class Grid? Just asking.

Comment: Don't know :P
I thought it was a good way to hide the grid outside!!!!

Answer (score 2):

That's how interfaces work. Everything in a public interface is public. If you have member variables in it they are automatically static. Try using an abstract class instead or move the member variables to the implementing class.

Comment: Yes, i thought about abstract classes, but probably i'll use the Patricia Shanahan's method!!! :)
Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite broad, but I'll try yo answer it: it is best to keep things as simple as possible:

- make your interfaces top level classes (ie in their own file)
- don't use inner classes unless necessary (I doubt they would be for this)

Comment: "don't use inner classes unless necessary (I doubt they would be for this)"
I'll keep this in mind :P Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In designing your interfaces, focus on the external functionality you want, and totally ignore how it is going to be implemented.

For example, if you have a need for a `BattleGrid` to be able to supply a `Grid` externally, you can declare them both as separate interfaces with `Grid getGrid();` as a method in `BattleGrid`. When writing a `BattleGrid` implementation you may choose to implement that by having a Grid implementation as an inner class in `BattleGrid`, but that has nothing at all to do with the `BattleGrid` interface.

If you don't need a `BattleGrid` to supply a `Grid` externally, don't mention `Grid` in the `BattleGrid` interface.

Comment: It looks a good idea!
Only a question, what u mean with "If you don't need a BattleGrid to supply a Grid externally, don't mention Grid in the BattleGrid interface."???
It means that i will not mention it in the Interface and only work with it into the implementation of the BattleGrid interface? Thank you!

Comment: @luca89pe Yes. An inner class that is not part of the outer class's external behavior does not need to be mentioned in its interface. It is just like a private field.

Comment: Thank you, i'll write as 2 separated interfaces, because i will need the Grid for drawing it into the GUI!
Now the question is: in the Grid, i need int rows and cols, and they can be static (but not final, because i have to initialize them when the player choose the difficulty), and the Cell matrixhas to be private!
I obviously can't to this in the interface. How can i do? Have i to omitt them and then implement them into the class?

Thank you!!!!!!! :)